# How to turn off verbose of python-camelot

Tags: python

I'm trying to turn off verbose logging process of camelot-py when use this package to extract table in PDF file.

I've tried:

```
table = camelot.read_pdf(os.path.join(self.target_folder, pdfName_map[key]), flavor='stream', pages='all', suppress_stdout=True)
```

But it still prints out lots of log. How to solve this problem? Thanks